# netlify deployment: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm trying deploy my project but failed.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjJU9.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcoAH.jpg)

but during the failed build, I received the following error message:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your build command to `CI= npm run build`.

In CI (Continuous Integration) mode, React leans on the side of error, that is any warnings are also treated as errors. Thus, just like any other error would cause the build to fail, the warnings in your code do the same. Either fix those warnings, to set the above build command.